# Github Password Changed - Git Issues

Tags: git, github

I recently changed my GitHub password and now local `git` repository won't seem to connect to the specified remote. Any time I try to push, I get this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://myusername@github.com/myusername/diary.git'
```

I am not sure if it is because of the password change ?

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if you have set a credential helper which would have cached the old password.

```
git config credential.helper
```

Then see [Caching your GitHub credentials in Git](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) from GitHub to, depending on your OS, update your password in your helper.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - @VonC all works now!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your old password is cached and you need to update with the new one.
You can try the way @VonC wrote. For windows users, if you want graphical solution, you can try from this:

```
Control Panel -> Credential Manager -> Generic Credentials
```

and remove your `username` `password`